# local hyperlinks in pdf using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pdf, pypdf

how to create local hyperlinks in pdf using python to point to page numbers.

I have read about pypdf but I am not sure if it can be done using it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can with [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter.addLink). I've never used it personally though.